# Why this FALSE condition is TRUE?

Tags: php

Why this FALSE condition is TRUE?

```
<?php
if(111111111111111119 == 111111111111111118)
{
    echo 'Condition is TRUE!';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Not confirmed. May be you mean without quotes?

Comment: You sure about this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TevroS

Comment: I can reproduce it: http://codepad.org/sM1LT1nt.

Comment: Why don't you assign the values to variables, and echo those to see what their value is? http://codepad.org/lxXlH5YK

Comment: This has to do with PHP type conversion rules. PHP will cast the operands so they have the same type when == is used.  `===` works as expected. Anyways, now the question has been edited, I am unsure if the quotes should be there or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> $a == $b is TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling
>
> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically

So because your strings are both numeric they are being converted to numbers first.
Then on some architectures numbers are so big that are overflowing maximum integer size and you are getting equal results.

Comment: type juggling is not the main issue `var_dump(111111111111111119 === 111111111111111118);` would still be true on 32 bit system

Comment: yes author changed question in the mean time so I was not sure what is the question exactly about :( Last sentence of answer still stands.

Answer (score 2):

PHP DOC

[Converting to string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> An integer or float is converted to a string representing the number textually (including the exponent part for floats). Floating point numbers can be converted using exponential notation (4.1E+6).

[Converting to integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

> If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even a notice will be issued when this happens!

My Guess you are using a 32 bits system so therefore

```
var_dump(111111111111111119,111111111111111118);
var_dump(111111111111111119 === 111111111111111118); // would be true on 32bit
```

Output

```
float 1.1111111111111E+17
float 1.1111111111111E+17
true
```

Simple Solution

```
    if(bcsub("111111111111111119", "111111111111111118") == "0")
    {
        // 32 bit true 
        var_dump("Am Free");
    }
```

Comment: They would be converted to float so `==` and `===` would always be true

Answer (score 0):

since it's converted into a numeric value

```
if('111111111111111119' == '111111111111111118')
{
echo 'Condition is TRUE!';
} else {
echo 'Condition is FALSE!';
}
// on 64 bit: condition is FALSE! (tested on my mac)
```

I'd assume that on 32bit machine it'd be true. Even when i remove the quotes on my mac it's shows false.

```
if('a111111111111111119' == 'a111111111111111118')
{
echo 'Condition is TRUE!';
} else {
echo 'Condition is FALSE!';
}
// condition is FALSE!
```